# LimitOffsetPagination not working globally by default in Generics View if added in settings

Tags: django, pagination, django-rest-framework

In my settings.py I have the following code :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
}
```

In my generics view I have the following code:

```
class ChildrenList(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = CheckItSerializer
    queryset = CheckIt.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            queryset = CheckIt.objects.filter(box=request.user.userdetail.box_obj.id).order_by('-id')
            serializer = CheckItSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            context = {"success": True, "message": "CheckIt List", "error": "", "data": serializer.data}
            return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as error:
            context = {'error': str(error), 'success': "false", 'message': 'Failed to get CheckIt Details.'}
            return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

If I am using get_queryset() in get method. It's giving me all the datas of that model

```
def get(self, request):
        try:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
            serializer = CheckItSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            context = {"success": True, "message": "CheckIt List", "error": "", "data": serializer.data}
            return Response(context, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How to make LimitOffsetPagination work on all the APIs without changing much of the APIs individually

Comment: Check the examples in the docs. Your `get` method doesn't use any of the inherited methods such as get_queryset. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#examples

Comment: I have updated the question. 
I need to use get method so as to get customise response

Comment: It's not clear to me what your goal is. The default result of `generics.ListAPIView.get` is paginated already. You don't need to override `get` unless you have something specific in mind. I suggest reading through the source code of the parent classes you are using to get a clearer understanding of what's happening. Here's the mixin class that provides pagination for `ListAPIView` https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py#L35

Answer (score 1):

Of cource it does not work.

You did override the `get` method which calls `ListModelMixin`'s list method where the pagination is handled.

Since you did that, you need to implement the pagination yourself again.

If you look at `ListModelMixin`, you can find this

```
class ListModelMixin(object):
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

You can take inspiration  from there and in your `get`, you need to call the part where it paginates the queryset.

Comment: Yes Now I know what was the issue. Thanks